# Assigning a CSS Class to a Variable Using jquery

Tags: jquery

Currently, I have:

```
<html>
<div class="yes1"><span><img src="img"></span></div>
</html>
<script>
var x = "='yes1'"
var y = "='yes2'"
$('.yes1').click(function () {
$('.yes1').find(x).replaceWith(y)
});
<script>
```

And I can't get the find and replaceWith to work.  I believe I'm not assigning the variables correctly.  Any helpe would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to change `<div class="yes1">` to be `<div class="yes2">` upon clicking?

Comment: Whoever down-voted this is a bit mean. It's a valid enough question and he's had an attempt at doing it himself, good for him. The question could be a little clearer, explaining that it's the class that needs to be changed, but everybody quickly understood what he wanted by reading his code, and gave detailed answers. I'll +1 it back to 0 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to change the contents of div yes1 with div yes2, then to make it work you would need the dot in front of the yes1 and yes2 (to make it a class selector, like so):

```
var x = ".yes1";
var y = ".yes2";
```

Alternatively, if you're trying to CHANGE the class, then your script needs to be altered:

CORRECTION:

```
$("yes1").removeClass("yes1").addClass("yes2");
```

(Thank you to the kind stackoverflow users who pointed out changes that needed to be made)

Comment: there is an `addClass` function for this.

Comment: True, but that implies he wants to add the class.  Based on his existing code, I believe he wanted to replace the class.

Comment: The `=` and `'` characters are not needed in the `x` and `y` strings. And when I say "not needed" I mean "will not work".

Comment: Then use both `addClass` and `removeClass`like in my answer, usage of `attr` for adding and removing classes is risky.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Thanks for the quote catch - I got in a hurry and copied the code from the question.  Edit made!

Comment: @nnnnnn. go figure, that answer was accpeted... =)

Comment: @ShadowStorm. nope it will toggle one class not two classes, see my or nnnnn answers.

Answer (score 1):

`<div class="yes1">` doesn't have any 'yes1' in it. so it will now work.

the `find` description is:

> Description: Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

so there is no 'yes1' inside of it.

if you just want to change the class, do this:

```
$('.yes1').click(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('yes1').addClass('yes2');
});
```

But because this code will be executed only once I would prefer the `one` function:

```
$('.yes1').one('click', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('yes1').addClass('yes2');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The "find" method finds and returns a child object or attribute of the object found by the "yes1", not the child attribute containing the value "yes1". What would work better is

```
var x='yes1';
var y='yes2'
$('.yes1').click(function () {
    $(this).removeClass(x).addClass(y);
});
```

Comment: Might as well chain those: `$(this).removeClass(x).addClass(y);`

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to tell what you are trying to achieve, but it kind of looks like upon click of a div with class "yes1" you want to change the class to be "yes2". If so you can do this:

```
$(".yes1").click(function() {
   $(this).removeClass("yes1").addClass("yes2");
});
```

That will change the class only of the clicked element, not other elements that also have the "yes1" class, because within the click event handler `this` refers to the clicked element. If you want to change *all* elements from "yes1" to "yes2" you can do this:

```
$(".yes1").removeClass("yes1").addClass("yes2");
```

If you want to do that with the variables `x` and `y` you need to set them to just the class name without `=` or quotes, so:

```
var x = "yes1",
    y = "yes2";

$("." + x).removeClass(x).addClass(y);
```

The [`.replaceWith()` method](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) that you were trying to use doesn't change attributes of the selected elements, it removes them entirely and replaces them with some other element(s). Given that the html markup you've shown doesn't have any other elements I don't think that's what you want to do, but if it was you'd use this syntax:

```
$(".yes1").replaceWith(".yes2");
```

Comment: thanks for the info.  I'm very new to jquery and this is quite helpful.